# ScrolltoIndex not working react-native on a flatlist

Tags: list, react-native, scroll, react-native-flatlist

I'm using a `flatList` to render items from a json file, I want to scroll to a specific index when a button is pressed, I declared the function for button press as below

```
goIndex = () => {
    this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true,index:5});
};
```

although it doesn't show any errors, the list is not moving to specified index.

> react-native: 0.55.4

Attaching code of FlatList.

```
<View>
    <FlatList   
        getItemLayout={(data, index) => { return {length: 33, index, offset: 33 * index} }}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={ () => <View style={ { width:"100%", height: .7, backgroundColor: 'rgba( 52,52,52,1)' } } /> }
        data={this.state.outverse}
        renderItem={({item,index}) =>
            <View style={styles2.flatview}>
                <Text style={styles2.name}>{++index}  {item} </Text>
            </View>
        }
    />
</View>
```

Comment: what is `this.flatListRef`?

Comment: it refers to the flatList defined in the code

Comment: Please share the component code in Question itself

Comment: @AravindS yeah attached it to the question

Comment: you shared a part only, please share whole component

Comment: attached whole component. @AravindS

Comment: Where is `this.flatListRef` in your component?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try adding reference to your `FlatList` component like below :

```
<View>
    <FlatList   
        getItemLayout={(data, index) => { return {length: 33, index, offset: 33 * index} }}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={ () => <View style={ { width:"100%", height: .7, backgroundColor: 'rgba( 52,52,52,1)' } } /> }
        data={this.state.outverse}
        ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
        renderItem={({item,index}) =>
            <View style={styles2.flatview}>
                <Text style={styles2.name}>{++index}  {item} </Text>
            </View>
        }
    />
</View>
```

And in `goIndex` function:

```
goIndex = () => {
    this.refs.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true,index:5});
};
```

Comment: @kiran: I implemented as per your code but i am not getting any methods related to flatlist when i refer to this.flatlistRef. What can be the issue ?

Comment: @Tejas Are you talking about this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.47/flatlist#methods?

Comment: @KirankumarDafda: yes none of these methods are accessible, I am using 0.55.4 version of react native. I somehow got access to scrollToIndex() using "ref._reactInternalFiber.child.stateNode.scrollToIndex()", but this also didnt work. Could you please help me out.

Comment: goIndex = () => {
    this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true,index:5});
};

Removing refs worked for me.Thank you

Comment: where we have to call goIndex method ?

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
<FlatList
        style={{
          marginLeft: 50,
          paddingTop: 0,
          paddingRight: 0
        }}
        ref={ref => {
          this.flatList_Ref = ref;  // <------ ADD Ref for the Flatlist 
        }}
        removeClippedSubviews={false}
        enableEmptySections={false}
        data={this.props.list}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this._renderItem1}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={this._renderSeparator}

      />
```

And then call a goIndex function:

```
goIndex = () => {

 this.flatList_Ref.scrollToIndex({animated: true,index:5});

};
```

Answer (score 0):

A fix that worked for me, was removing `flex:1` on the `contentContainerStyle` prop.

Answer (score -1):

Anyone using function based component with useRef hook, you can do it like this.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const myListRef = useRef(null);

  const goIndex = (index) => {
    myListRef.current.scrollToIndex({index});
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
        ref={ref => myListRef.current = ref}
        getItemLayout={(data, index) => { return {length: 33, index, offset: 33 * index} }}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={ () => <View style={ { width:"100%", height: .7, backgroundColor: 'rgba( 52,52,52,1)' } } /> }
        data={this.state.outverse}
        renderItem={({item,index}) =>
            <View style={styles2.flatview}>
                <Text style={styles2.name}>{++index}  {item} </Text>
            </View>
        }
    />
  );
}
```

This answer reiterates what others answered above, but simplifies for Function based components.